# Devise Invitable Terms of Service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

I am trying to add a terms of service checkbox to my devise invitable view.
So an invite is sent out and the Engineer clicks the accept invite link and arrives at the form below:

```
<h2><%= t 'devise.invitations.edit.header' %></h2>

<%= simple_form_for resource, as: resource_name, url: invitation_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put } do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :invitation_token %>

  <%= f.input :first_name %>
  <%= f.input :last_name %>

  <%= f.input :password %>
  <%= f.input :password_confirmation %>

  <%= f.input :terms_of_service, as: :boolean, required: true, label: ("I agree to the #{link_to 'Terms of Service', page_path('terms'), target: :_blank}").html_safe %>

  <%= f.button :submit, t("devise.invitations.edit.submit_button") %>
<% end %>
```

My model is:

```
class Engineer < ApplicationRecord
  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessor :terms_of_service
.
.
.
  validates_acceptance_of :terms_of_service, if: :invitation_accepted_at?, acceptance: true, allow_nil: false
```

I have a custom devise controller:

```
class CustomDeviseController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
.
.
.
  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:first_name, :last_name])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:accept_invitation, keys: [:first_name, :last_name, :terms_of_service])
  end
```

I get the form error "Terms of service must be accepted", which tells me the validations are running. The problem appears to be that the terms of service fails as it is nil and so the validations fail. I can't see why when I tick the checkbox it doesn't pass that and meet the validations?

--- UPDATED ---

The params hash generated is:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"aoGCMoYRcmJ2EmpM8L+UmQQcB99FScgA6nFM0kY+53dxDodCZDislej48+lBL4Qcb5ZgAcGHyd1A+3qkIol6KA==", "engineer"=>{"invitation_token"=>"e9oVkxuYMtX9Fzxao7xR", "first_name"=>"sad", "last_name"=>"test", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "terms_of_service"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Create Account"}
Unpermitted parameter: :terms_of_service
```

Comment: Can you post the params hash that is being generated on form submit?

Comment: Well, I see that the action triggered is update. Try putting `:terms_of_service` in `account_update` params

Comment: Still no luck. If I remove the allow_nil: false on the validates_acceptance_of it passes even when checkbox is unchecked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out because I had a customer devise controller but was also name spacing the invitables stuff under Engineers. I was permitting the params in the wrong file.

I had to permit them in the Engineers::InvitationsController instead.